# sending mail using swiftmail

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer

I am learning to use swift mail to send mail. I tried below code to send mail even the php success but didn't send any mail to my hotmail. I tried using 465 and 587 but both not sending mail to my hotmail.

```
 <?php

 require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';


 echo 'Mail sent <br />';  

 $username = 'vic.ho******@gmail.com';
 $password = 'password';

 $transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587, 'ssl')
 ->setUsername($username)
 ->setPassword($password);

 $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);



 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('vic.ho******@gmail.com'))
  ->setTo(array('dark*****@hotmail.com'))
  ->setBody('Test Message Body')
  ;


 $result = $mailer->send($message);

 echo $result;

 ?>
```

before this i tried use the code below but come out error 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''vic.ho******@gmail.com'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\Users\Popo\Desktop\xampp\xampp\htdocs\test\mailtry.php on line 13"

this is the code

```
 <?php

 require_once 'lib/swift_required.php'; 


 $transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465,'ssl')
  ->setUsername($this-> 'vic.ho******@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword($this-> 'password');

 $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);



 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
 ->setFrom(array('vic.hon******@gmail.com'))
 ->setTo(array('dark******@hotmail.com'))
 ->setBody('Test Message Body')
  ;


  $result = $mailer->send($message);

  echo $result;


  echo 'line 58 <br />';

  ?>
```

should i enable any configuration in the php.ini or mercury for sending mail?Or is due to firewall in my school so i cannot send mail? Because now i'm using XAMPP to sending mail. Hope someone can teach me or tell me other alternative ways to send mail. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't in object context, so `$this` is irrelevant.
2. Objects cannot have bare strings as properties, they have variables as properties. Just use strings.